# Printing toString information out of List made of different objects

Tags: java, oop

I'm having some issues with how I should approach this problem.
    I have a **Boat** class which contains a *toString()* and getters and setters.
    **PowerBoat** class which extends functionality and overrides *toString()* method from it's superclass.
    **SailBoat** class which extends functionality and overrides *toString()* method from it's superclass.
    In my test class I am adding different PowerBoats, SailBoats in a ArrayList of type of Boat.
    **I need to find the most expensive boat and print a *toString()* information about that boat.**

```
public class Boat {
    String color;
    int length;

    public Boat(){
        color = "white";
        length = 20;
    }

    public Boat(String color, int length){
        setColor(color);
        setLength(length);
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public boolean setColor(String color) {
        switch (color){
            case "white" : this.color = color;
            case "red" : this.color = color;
            case "blue" : this.color = color;
            case "yellow" : this.color = color;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public boolean setLength(int length) {
        if(length >= 20 && length <= 50) {
            this.length = length;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Boat{" +
                "color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", length=" + length +
                '}';
    }
}

public class PowerBoat extends Boat {
    int engineSize;

    public PowerBoat(){
        super();
        setEngineSize(5);
    }

    public PowerBoat(String color, int length, int engineSize){
        super(color, length);
        setEngineSize(engineSize);
    }

    public boolean setEngineSize(int engineSize){
        if(engineSize >= 5 && engineSize <= 350){
            this.engineSize = engineSize;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getEngineSize() {
        return engineSize;
    }

    public int calcPrice(){
        return 5000 + length + 300 + engineSize * 20;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() +
                "engineSize= " + engineSize +
                '}' + " Price " + calcPrice();
    }
}


    public class SailBoat extends Boat {
        int numSails = 0;

        public SailBoat(){
            numSails = 1;
        }

        public SailBoat(String color, int length, int numSails){
            super(color, length);
            setNumSails(numSails);
        }

        public int getNumSails() {
            return numSails;
        }

        public boolean setNumSails(int numSails) {
            if(numSails >= 1 && numSails <= 4){
                this.numSails = numSails;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int calcPrice(){
            return length * 1000 + numSails * 2000;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() +
                    "numSails= " + numSails +
                    '}' + " price " + calcPrice();
        }
    }

    public class Inventory {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<Boat> list = new ArrayList();
            Boat powerBoat = new PowerBoat("blue", 46, 60);
            Boat powerBoat1 = new PowerBoat("yellow", 42, 55);
            Boat sailBoat = new SailBoat("white", 32, 1);
            Boat sailBoat1 = new SailBoat("red", 24, 2);
            list.add(powerBoat);
            list.add(powerBoat1);
            list.add(sailBoat);
            list.add(sailBoat1);

            int sumSailBoat = 0;
            int sumPowerBoat = 0;
            int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            for(Boat b : list){
                if (b instanceof SailBoat){
                    sumSailBoat+= ((SailBoat) b).calcPrice();
                    if (((SailBoat) b).calcPrice() > largest){
                        if(b instanceof SailBoat) {
                            largest = ((SailBoat) b).calcPrice();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (b instanceof PowerBoat){
                    sumPowerBoat+= ((PowerBoat) b).calcPrice();
                    if(((PowerBoat) b).calcPrice() > largest){
                        if(b instanceof PowerBoat){
                            largest = ((PowerBoat) b).calcPrice();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            int totalSum = sumSailBoat + sumPowerBoat;
            System.out.println("Total price of sail boats is " + sumSailBoat);
            System.out.println("Total price of sail boats is " + sumPowerBoat);
            System.out.println("Total price of sail and power boats is " + totalSum);
            System.out.println("Most expensive boat is " + largest);
        }
    }
```

**I managed to find the largest price but how can I print the toString information about that Boat?**

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type you can use:

`System.out.println("My PowerBoat " + ((PowerBoat) b));`

`System.out.println("My SailBoat " + ((SailBoat) b));`

Answer (score 0):

If you already found the object you need to print store it in a variable and just call toString on it.

`Boat b = //whichever one you found here from the arraylist`

`System.out.println(b.toString())`

Since classes in java use dynamic binding, even if your reference is of the superclass, the contents of the method should still be the same.

Comment: The best I can get is getting largest price out of PowerBoats and largest price out of SailBoats. The problem is comparing largest PowerBoat price and largest SailBoat price, please take a look at my Inventory class and I think you will see my point

Comment: I see, your issue is that the Boat Class does not have a calcPrice method you can add one in and return something arbitrary like 0 or null. Additionally, if you do not need to ever instantiate the boat class at all in your program, you can just make it an abstract class. See the 2nd point in Arkadiy's post

Answer (score 0):

`[teach-me]` You seem to have some misconceptions on OO design and java method calls. Please talk to your teachers or read some OO/Java books. Start with the concept of `abstract` and `final` in Java - that should give you some idea how methods are called and how inheritance can be used.

That being said, you need to do 2 things.

(1) To answer your question, in addition to `int largest`, also keep `Boat mostExpensiveBoat`, update it at the same time you update `largest`. Then at the end print `mostExpensiveBoat.toString()`.

(2) You need to make calcPrice() an abstract method of `Boat`. Then when you call `b.calcPrice()`, the method that matches the type of object `b` refers to will "magically" be invoked. No need check `instanceof` or to cast.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'm aware that my understanding of OO is not the best. From your suggestions now I understood the term abstract much better. Do you have any good books that will make me understand OO better?

Comment: I learned my OO by investigating source code of a great OO GUI framework, so no books from me :) . All the books I've read since are just "how to do it well", not "what it is". One possible advice would be to learn Smalltalk - the original OO language. In any case, there had been a revolution in OO around 10 years ago, when we finally realized that inheritance of classes is harmful and we should use composition and interfaces,

Comment: Some other people recommend books: https://www.amazon.com/dp/0735619654/?tag=stackoverflow17-20

Comment: Great stuff, sounds promising!

Answer (score 0):

It will be better, to make **calcPrice()** part of Boat interface:

```
abstract class Boat {
    String color;
    int length;

    public Boat(){
        color = "white";
        length = 20;
    }

    public Boat(String color, int length){
        setColor(color);
        setLength(length);
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public boolean setColor(String color) {
        switch (color){
            case "white" : this.color = color;
            case "red" : this.color = color;
            case "blue" : this.color = color;
            case "yellow" : this.color = color;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public boolean setLength(int length) {
        if(length >= 20 && length <= 50) {
            this.length = length;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public abstract int calcPrice();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Boat{" +
                "color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", length=" + length +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then you can make search in this way:

```
    int sumSailBoat = 0;
    int sumPowerBoat = 0;
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Boat boatWithLargestPrice = null;

    for (Boat b : list) {
        int boatPrice = b.calcPrice();
        if (boatPrice > largest) {
            largest = boatPrice;
            boatWithLargestPrice = b;
        }

        if (b instanceof SailBoat) {
            sumSailBoat += boatPrice;
        } else {
            sumPowerBoat += boatPrice;
        }       
    }

    int totalSum = sumSailBoat + sumPowerBoat;
    System.out.println("Total price of sail boats is " + sumSailBoat);
    System.out.println("Total price of power boats is " + sumPowerBoat);
    System.out.println("Total price of sail and power boats is " + totalSum);
    System.out.println("Most expensive boat is " + boatWithLargestPrice + " with price " + largest);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would upvote it but my reputation < 15

Answer (score 0):

By making your `Boat` class `abstract` you can require all `Boat`s to implement `calcPrice`. Then you can just treat all `Boat`s the same.

```
public abstract class Boat {
    final String color;
    final int length;

    public Boat(String color, int length) {
        this.color = color;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public abstract int calcPrice();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Boat{" +
                "color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", length=" + length +
                '}';
    }
}

public class PowerBoat extends Boat {
    final int engineSize;

    public PowerBoat(String color, int length, int engineSize) {
        super(color, length);
        this.engineSize = engineSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int calcPrice() {
        return 5000 + length + 300 + engineSize * 20;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() +
                "engineSize= " + engineSize +
                '}' + " Price " + calcPrice();
    }
}

public class SailBoat extends Boat {
    final int numSails;

    public SailBoat(String color, int length, int numSails) {
        super(color, length);
        this.numSails = numSails;
    }

    @Override
    public int calcPrice() {
        return length * 1000 + numSails * 2000;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() +
                "numSails= " + numSails +
                '}' + " price " + calcPrice();
    }
}

public void test() {
    ArrayList<Boat> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new PowerBoat("blue", 46, 60));
    list.add(new PowerBoat("yellow", 42, 55));
    list.add(new SailBoat("white", 32, 1));
    list.add(new SailBoat("red", 24, 2));

    Boat mostExpensiveBoat = null;
    int totalSum = 0;

    for (Boat boat : list) {
        totalSum += boat.calcPrice();
        if(mostExpensiveBoat == null || boat.calcPrice() > mostExpensiveBoat.calcPrice() ) {
            mostExpensiveBoat = boat;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total price of sail and power boats is " + totalSum);
    System.out.println("Most expensive boat is " + mostExpensiveBoat);
}
```

Comment: **By making your Boat class abstract you can require all Boats to implement calcPrice. Then you can just treat all Boats the same.** - Much obliged!